# Simple Plotting Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I am trying to create a simple quick plotting script for any function of x. I would like to pass the literal return of f(x) in it's algebraic form so that it can be used as the plot title.
for example:
If I have a function
`def f1(x): return x**2`
I would like to pass (x**2) to my plot function as a string so that can be used for the plot tile.

so far I have:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f1(x): return x**2 

def create_plot_data(f,xmin,xmax,n):
    xs = [xmin + (xmax - xmin )*i/float(n-1) for i in range(n)]
    ys = [f(x) for x in xs]
    return[xs,ys]

def plot_f(func):
    Plot_title = 'Plot of ' +str(func())#would like the algebraic form of the return of given function.
    plot_label = func.__name__
    xmin = -5
    xmax = 5
    n = 11
    plot_data = create_plot_data(func,xmin,xmax,n)
    xs = plot_data[0]
    ys = plot_data[1]
    plt.plot(xs,ys, label = plot_label)    
    plt.title(Plot_title)
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)')
    plt.savefig(plot_label + '.png')
    plt.show()
    return

plot_f(f1)
```

so for `def f1(x): return x**2` it should read "plot of: `x**2`
for `def f2(x): return (((b-a)**2)**0.5)` the title should read `(((b-a)**2)**0.5)`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XvA2.png)

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you want literally parse algebraic functions into a python function, then eval with numeric values and then plot?

Comment: I want my plot script to call a given function, solve and plot it. in addition to this i would like to create a title for the plot that is derived from the given function.